# LSTM predicting next product in sequence with time

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have a dataset that contains, for every customer, the sequence of products they took over the last 10 years. Every product has an execution date, which is the time a customer took that product. The columns go up to 20 products, and null values are populated if they have fewer products.

| customer_id | product_1 | exec_date_1 | product_2 | exec_date_2 | product_3 | exec_date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2020 | B | 1/18/2020 |  |  |
| 2 | B | 5/1/6/2020 | C | 1/18/2021 | D | 4/20/2022 |

I want to create a model (neural network suggested) where you take all sequences of products and predict what comes next. So you take n-1 products to predict the last/most recent product. Training on sequences alone, however, ignores the time component, which the gap between each product. What I did is introduced time gap between consecutive products as features, and trained the model on that.

An example of the inputs and target would look like this:

```
[[A, 0], [B, 6], [B, 12], [C, 18]] --> [D, 12]
```

..where 6 is the number of months between A and B, etc. 0 just corresponds to the first product (which in our case will be their current account, so no product can be taken before it).

But even if I add time as a separate feature, I can only predict the sequence (D). I can't predict the time it will take to take the next product after C (so 12 months - gap between C and D), correct?

Is there a way to have the product next in sequence AND the time to take that product, as outputs?

I trained a simple LSTM model for this:

```
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(reshaped_padded_X.shape[1], 1))
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(lstm)
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)(dropout)
dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(lstm)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(dropout)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(y_cat.shape[1], activation='softmax')(dense)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

Shape of input is `(sample_size, 16, 2)` where 16 is the sequence length (plus padding) and 2 are the features (sequence and time). LSTM works best with time-based sequence according to my research. Not sure if there's a more straightforward way to achieve this.

Comment: RNN lies on the assumption of temporal dependence, ie that what happens on time T depends on that happens before T... pretty sure that predicting "the next product" is not something you can do with this, both because the sequences and outputs are too sparse, and because the networks is not magic, it can't predict what a user will buy and when, it's too difficult

Comment: you might do that if you have a giant database of informations about the user, but having only product-date pairs, is far from creating a perfect profile of the user, and even with that, you can't predict "when" it will happen

Comment: this is only going to maybe work if you have like 5 products, but anything greater than this, is unapproachable. As people use to say, you are solving the wrong problem

Comment: also, pleeease consider using a test set, because this is one of those problems where model seems good but it's just because it's overfitting

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have customer information (age, income, etc.) so we can add those as features I guess? I just want to know if it's possible to have multiple inputs and multiple outputs. I've seen the examples on the TF documentation. Do I have to just supply the sequence and time as separate inputs to the model, and have two different Dense layers as outputs?

Comment: you can just do `dense1 = Dense(...)(dropout)` and then `dense2 = Dense(...)(dropout)` to have 2 branches, and finally `model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output_layer_1, output_layer_2])`, if this is your question

Comment: So the input will be an array of sequence and time (so [A, 0], etc.), right? How would the shape look like? Will it be (samples, timestep (length of sequence), features), where features is 2 because we have sequence and time?  And the output layers will be similar I guess, just one Dense(number of products) and another Dense(time quarters) I'm assuming?